# gorillaでセッションを破棄（削除）する方法を知りたい

Tags: go

http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions
https://github.com/gorilla/sessions

Golangのセッション管理でgorillaを使っています。
持っているセッションを全て破棄してから新しくセッションにデータを保存したいです。
その際にセッションを破棄する方法がわからないので知っている方がいたら教えてください。

```
func clearSession1(session *sessions.Session) {
    session.Options = &sessions.Options{MaxAge: -1, Path: "/"}
}
/*
  １つ目のやり方だとsessionはすぐに消されない
  リクエストの処理が終わると消されている
*/

func clearSession2(session *sessions.Session) {
    session.Values = nil
}
/*
  ２つ目のやり方だとセッションはすぐに消せるが再度セッションに保存するときに以下のエラーが起こる
  panic: runtime error: assignment to entry in nil map
*/
```

Comment: 2番目の方法の場合は `session.Values = make(map[interface{}]interface{})` とするのではないでしょうか(新規に map オブジェクトを生成)。ただ、ソースコードを見ますと `NewSession()` というメソッドがありますので、そちらを利用した方が良い様な気もしますが…

Answer (score 1):

以下のように、`session.Options` を変更した後、
`session.Save()` する事でご希望の動作になるかと思います。

```
func clearSession1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Requset, session *sessions.Session) {
    session.Options = &sessions.Options{MaxAge: -1, Path: "/"}
    session.Save(r, w)
}
```